# Mongodb negative regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, nosql

How do you do a negative regex query in Mongodb?

I want to find all documents, where "Name" does not contain the string "james". E.g. filter out "james" or "john james" or "john james peter" or "somethingjames"

This works, but ONLY if the string begins with "james".

```
db.name.find({"name":/^((?!james).)/i});
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You mean where the entry does *not* contain `james`? `/^(?!.*james)/i`?

Comment: @Wiktor - correct! Edited the question. I am aware of the other questions, but they dont resolve this.

Comment: Yes, the answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24743196/3832970

Comment: Worked - thanks a lot @Wiktor!